# Is there performance benifits of using OpenGLES 2.0 over OpenGLES 1.1 on Adreno 200 (AMD Z430)?

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

Since Adreno 200 can't handle much (or almost anything) in terms of fragment shaders other than two-liners that straight up clone OpenGLES 1.x fixed pipeline functionality, is there any reason to use them?

On an old phone(HTC Desire with Adreno 200):

1. Is there a performance benefit/penalty to using GLES 2.0 over 1.1 (most importantly, multitexturing)?
2. If I use OpenGLES 1.1, who does the vertex transforms CPU or GPU?

Answer (score 0):

Whether OpenGL ES 1.1 or 2.0 is hardware accelerated depends on the target platform (both software and hardware).

Anyway, moving from 1.1 to 2.0 won't help improving performance. If 2.0 is hardware accelerated then you can bet 1.1 is also.

I suggest to go for OpenGL ES 2.0 and its not backward compatible